# Hiding any mesh when another mesh touches it

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a bunch of balls [Meshes], I want them to disappear or hide when another object [Mesh] (A specific Mesh) touches it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Describe the way they should disappear. You can use dynamic paint.

[image]

[image]

But it seems like a job for Animation Nodes: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes

Comment: It's like I have several cubes and One Sphere, When I move sphere through those cubes it hides or deactivates every cube it touches.